# Difference between Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers and Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

What is the difference between "Eclipse IDE for Java(EE) Developers" and "Eclipse Juno"?

I will be working on website development in JSP using Apache Tomcat web server.

Are there any migration issues in the near future from one edition of Eclipse to another?

Comment: 1) Difference between Eclipse IDE for Java EE devs and classic Eclipse IDE: Eclipse for JavaEE devs has more plugins installed. :) 2) Never had any issues with projects when changing Eclipse versions.

Comment: @brano: thanks but what is the difference between the two ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What is the difference between Eclipse IDE for Java(EE) Developers and Eclipse Juno .

The concepts are orthogonal.

"Juno" is just the fantasy name for the IDE version 4.2. Different (succesive) releases are called by a number (3.7, 4.2, 4.3 ...) and also by a [codename](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29#Name):

```
Eclipse 3.7 = Indigo
Eclipse 4.2 = Juno
Eclipse 4.3 = Kepler
Eclipse 4.4 = Luna
Eclipse 4.5 = Mars
```

Each release, in turn, can be downloaded in several packaged variants, which differ only in which plugins (functionality) are included ("Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers", "Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers", etc).

There are usually no relevant issues in migrating from one version to another, in general you should try with the last version.

Answer (score 5):

Eclipse IDE has more versions like

```
Eclipse 3.7 = Indigo
Eclipse 4.2 = Juno
Eclipse 4.3 = Kepler
Eclipse 4.4 = Luna
Eclipse 4.5 = Mars
Eclipse 4.6 = Neon (planned)
```

so `Juno` is not different IDE it is a version of `Eclipse`IDE see [wiki eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29)

Answer (score 2):

> Different versions of Eclipse have been named after different
>   celestial bodies, more specifically planets or planets' natural
>   satellites. Examples are: Europa, Ganymede, Callisto, Galileo, Luna,
>   and recently, Mars. The next version coming in 2016 has been named
>   Neon.

It is always recommended to use the latest version of Eclipse IDE. As Juno was released it had more support and better than Indigo and Helios. But as more future versions are released the support and stability becomes better. And I had no problems in switching to any future releases. In fact, performance and stability just got better as I moved on to the latest versions every year. As of August 2015, the list of all eclipse versions,

```
3.0       ==   Not Named released in 2004  
3.1       ==   Not Named released in 2005  
3.2       ==   Callisto released in 2006  
3.3       ==   Europa released in 2007  
3.4       ==   Ganymede released in 2008  
3.5       ==   Galileo released in 2009  
3.6       ==   Helios released in 2010  
3.7       ==   Indigo released in 2011  
3.8 & 4.2 ==   Juno released in 2012  
4.3       ==   Kepler released in 2013  
4.4       ==   Luna released in 2014  
4.5       ==   Mars released in 2015  
4.6       ==   Neon(Future release expected in 2016)
```

*Notes:- There is a 3.8 release of Eclipse Juno; it is not promoted on the main downloads page, but a packaged distribution is available for [download](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.8.2-201301310800/). Eclipse 3.8 provides bugfixes for Indigo & adds Java 7 support, and its maintenance was dual streamed with 4.2. Source - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29)*

Comment: Late is better than never I suppose