# Scanner is running before any part and needs two input in order to run

Tags: java

```
package happy;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PiVal {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); //initialise scanner 
        String val= Double.toString(Math.PI); //Storing PI to string
        System.out.println(val);//Printing the stored value
        System.out.println("Enter the value");//Screen output to print
        int till =s.nextInt(); //taking user input storing in till
        till+=2; //increasing value to  +2 as only want to change after decima
        if(till>15) //Checking if variable value more than 15
        {
            System.out.println("Out of bounds");
        }
        System.out.println(val.substring(0,till));
        s.close();
}

}
```

My  code looks like this very simple code i know just revising some stuffs but the thing i am not able to get my head around is why i need to input 2 times just to run the code and the "Print " command is not running very first it is running after the scanner input.

OutPut looks like this

```
8
8
3.141592653589793
Enter the value
3.14159265
```

Edit:
Eclipse LUNA

Comment: Works fine for me on eclipse. What IDE are you using? My output is totally different

Comment: does it output that consistently? or did that only happen once?

Comment: which of those lines are user input?

Comment: @Twtheo The first 2

Comment: @Tommy Ohhhh I gotchya, misunderstood what was happening

Comment: EclipseLuna! @Twtheo the user input is " int till "

Comment: @Tommy eclipse Luna

Comment: This code does not produce that output.

Comment: @matt i just ran the code again it is giving the same output for me.

Comment: @ShuchinPrakash The code you have provided does not produce the "output" you have shown. Paste the actual code.

Comment: @Tommy consistent. i even used this scanner method in other programs and it is giving me same issue also as Console is not working in my IDE. Thanks

Comment: @matt it is the actual code i just ran it. What output it is giving on your system?

Comment: The first thing that happens is it prints PI. Maybe there is some issue with your environment.

Comment: `3.141592653589793\n
Enter the value\n
8\n
3.14159265
`

Comment: @matt That's looks good enough hmm may be there is any kind of problem with my environment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that the code produces the correct output for everyone else, there is something wrong with your IDE. Try running your program in another IDE and see if that helps. You should update Eclipse Luna(if any updates are available) and restart it(just quit and reopen). That should solve your issue, however if it does not, You may need to use a different Environment.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22950403/difference-between-eclipse-ide-for-java-ee-developers-and-eclipse-juno) dude. It's always recommended by the developer of eclipse to use the most updated version of eclipse. But of course, it's not necessary all the time. However, luna is using version 4.4, while the second latest eclipse is already using 4.6 which is ahead by at least 2-3 years.

What you're facing could be some issues that no one really has officially brought up before. It's just how certain IDE works behind which programmers like us may not understand. It's similar to `Quincy` who doesn't follow the correct order during program runtime.